How do you mock a static method (not void) to have different behavior on two different invocations?
I need to mock a static method, so that it throws an exception the first time it is called, and returns some value, the second time it is called.  I know how to mock it so that it throws an exception and mock it so that it returns a value, but am not sure how to make it behave differently on two subsequent calls.
Also, how would I test two subsequent calls to a mocked static method in a single test?  Would I be able to do it in one MockedStatic block or do I need two separate Mocked static blocks for each call?  This question will make more sense in the example below:
/** Util class containing static. method to be mocked */
public final class VariableUtil {   
            
  //. static method to be mocked.
  public static JsonValue createJsonVariable(Object variableValue) throws Exception{…..}
}
    
/** JsonValue class */
public interface JsonValue extends PrimitiveValue<String> {
}

/** Class that uses the VariableUtil class */
public class SomeClass {

    //. Method that makes two calls to the static method.
    public void someMethod() {
    
        try {
            //. Make the FIRST call to the static method.
            //. This time it SHOULD throw an exception

            VariableUtil.createVariable(
                Collections.singletonList(someObject));

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            //. The first call’s exception should bring execution into 
            //. this catch block, where we,  
            //. make the SECOND call to the static method.  This time 
            //. it SHOULD NOT throw an exception and instead return a mocked value.

            JsonValue someJsonValue = VariableUtil.createVariable(
                Collections.singletonList(someObject));
        }
    }
}

/**.JUnit.*/:
@Test
public void testCreateVariable() {

    //. The below DOES NOT WORK.  How would I mock it so that, 
    //. on the first invocation, it throws an Exception 
    //. and, on the second, it returns a value?
 
    try (final MockedStatic<VariableUtil> variableUtilMock = 

        //. Mock throwing an exception.
        mockStatic(VariableUtil.class)) {
          variableUtilMock.when(() -> VariableUtil.createJsonVariable(processingFailureErrorMessage))
                .thenThrow(new Exception());
        
        //. Mock returning a value.
        variableUtilMock.when(() -> VariableUtil.createJsonVariable(processingFailureErrorMessage))
                .thenReturn("someJsonValue");
            
            SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass();
            someObject.someMethod();
        }
}


The processingFailureErrorMessage is used as an argument in both when clauses: have you tried to put different (and fixed) values in mock declaration?

Why would createVariable work the second time it is called with the exact same parameter?

You have to chain the thenThrow/thenReturn calls if you want consecutive calls (with same arguments) to return different values.
If you don't chain, earlier stubbings are overwritten.
  variableUtilMock.when(() -> VariableUtil.createJsonVariable(processingFailureErrorMessage))
        .thenThrow(new Exception())
        .thenReturn("someJsonValue");

See Stubbing consecutive calls in the Mockito docs.
